# RewriteEngine Adds relative path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have such rewrite rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^monkey.pl(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.monkey.pl/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^horse.html$ /dog.html
```

and when I go to the monkey.pl/horse.html I get the message:

> The requested URL /home/login/monkey/dog.html was not found on this server.

How can I get this to work. Basically what I'm trying to do is to change address of urls like:
http://www.monkey.pl/produkty.php?strona=1 
to be displayed as
http://www.monkey.pl/produkty/czesci_do_mixokretow.html
but none of my rules are working. Therefore I'm trying to come with solution.

I tried many varations and I couldn't get it to work. I don't want to rewrite whole page. Just 6 pages which I need to change url and that's all. Fixed translation url => url.

Comment: How exactly does this translate from `http://www.monkey.pl/produkty.php?strona=1` to `http://www.monkey.pl/produkty/czesci_do_mixokretow.html`? The rewritten URL has no ID value or name that seems to match.

Comment: It does not translate. But I need it to be fixed translation. Not based on ID or something just on URL.

Comment: What is your specific URL structure you are starting with. Is it the query string or is it a file? I'm asking because you provided 2 different types of URLs. A html to html and php query string to html. Which one are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to translate http://www.monkey.pl/produkty.php?strona=1 to http://www.monkey.pl/produkty/czesci_do_mixo‌​kretow.html but the horse and dog example I just gave because I was trying to see if the simplest translation would work. It didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only doing a handful of URLs then you can do them this way.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /+produkty\.php\?strona=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /produkty/czesci_do_mixo‌​kretow\.html [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^produkty/czesci_do_mixo‌​kretow\.html$ /produkty.php?strona=1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^horse\.html$ /dog.html [L]
```

Comment: Thank you but it still does not translate. URLs stay the same and monkey.pl/horse.html throws still the same error.

Comment: What do you mean it stays the same? What are you typing in the browser? You should be using `produkty/czesci_do_mixo‌​kretow\.html`

Comment: Yeah, thank you. It's working but I thought that when I come to produkty.php?strona=1 then it'd change the url to produkty/czesci_do_mixokretow.html as well as all hyperlinks which link to this page. Because what is the point to rewriting this when google does not see the pretty url? Thank you for your help once again.

Comment: That can be done as well. I updated the answer so if they browse the old php URL it will redirect to the new one also.

Comment: Thank you! You're amazing. You helped me in the way that I understand the whole process now.